# Экспортировать историю Skype 8

Tags: javascript, поиск-программ, skype

Хочу собрать историю с 8го скайпа, пока не стало слишком поздно - встречается информация (не пойму, насколько достоверная), что она хранится на сервере только 60 дней. Но сам скайп функциональность по экспорту не содержит (точнее, содержит, но толдьео для 7й версии).

Есть мысль открыть веб-версию скайпа и скриптом пройтись по контактам, проскроллить чат (там виртуализация списка, просто проскроллить в начало - не вариант) и стащить из html-разметки всё, что там есть. Ну либо посмотреть, как там отправляются запросы (используются веб-сокеты) и тащить данные оттуда. Но ведь это всё ещё и реализовывать надо, а выглядит не очень тривиально.

Может быть есть какие-то готовые решения?